# Find the generating function for the finite sequence 0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have the sequence $\{0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and I need to find a generating function.

I found the answer to be $\sum n x^{n+2}$. However to find the nth term, I would use $n-2$, correct? But then for $n=0,1,2$, I would have a negative. How do I account for those zeroes?

Comment: Is the sequence supposed to be $\{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots\}$?

Comment: no it is finite

Comment: I would say :)      max(n - 2,0),  n from 0 to $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generating function is $x^3+2x^4+3x^5+4x^6+5x^7$

which you can write as

- $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{5} n x^{n+2}$
- $\displaystyle x^2 \sum_{n=0}^{5} n x^{n}$
- $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{7} (n-2) x^{n}$
- $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{n=0}^{7} (n-2) x^{n}\right) + 2 + x $
- $\dfrac{x^3(1-6x^5+5x^6)}{(1-x)^2}$ 
  or as a variety of other things

Comment: So I should not worry about accounting for the zeroes in my generating function? or does the fact that it starts on $x^3$ imply that?

Comment: Having no constant, linear or quadratic terms means that it starts with zeros, yes

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{{x}^{3}}{{\left( 1-x\right) }^{2}}$ will give $\{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots\}$

Comment: Series[(x^3 (1 - 6 x^5 - 5 x^6))/(1 - x)^2, {x, 0, 7}] works, but if I use Series[(x^3 (1 - 6 x^5 - 5 x^6))/(1 - x)^2, {x, 0, 15}] I get a different answer. Didn't OP ask for the GF of a finite (...) series? - My point being: isn't your initial answer the best? - But what if I want to describe a finite sequence of i.e. 9000 elements?

Comment: @niloderoock You might want to check the sign in $+5x^6$.  If you try [`Series[(x^3 (1 - 6 x^5 + 5 x^6))/(1 - x)^2, {x, 0, 15}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B%28x%5E3+%281+-+6+x%5E5+%2B+5+x%5E6%29%29%2F%281+-+x%29%5E2%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+15%7D%5D) then you get no additional terms

Comment: Interesting! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You were not accurate enough by omitting the index range in the summation.

The generating function is
$$0x^0+0x^1+0x^2+1x^3+2x^4+3x^5+4x^6+5x^7=\sum_{n=3}^7(n-2)x^n.$$

The zeroes are accounted for by just omitting the corresponding powers.

Note that the following representations are equivalent:

$$\sum_{n=2}^7(n-2)x^n=\sum_{n=3}^7(n-2)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^5nx^{n+2}=\sum_{n=1}^5nx^{n+2}.$$

In no case do you have to evaluate a negative coefficient.

If you really want to represent all terms, use
$$\sum_{n=0}^7\max(n-2,0)x^n.$$
Another option is to indeed use negative terms, but compensate them:
$$\sum_{n=0}^7(n-2)x^n+2+x.$$